# 16.04 Automatic Updates

Tags: updates, security, update-manager

I have been running 16.04 on my desktop for about 2 months now.  I have yet to see it ask me to install updates. I have not changed the default settings, and all the appropriate boxes appear to be checked.

How can I force it to check for updates, and make it automatic in the future?

This is what my settings tab looks like.  Could it be that they're downloaded and installed unbeknownst to me?:

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: "Download and install automatically" means do it, no questions asked. So yes, updates are downloaded and installed without asking, prompting, notifying or nagging.

Comment: nothing to be done here, the OP asked about a problem that didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html) is solution. I believe, it can help.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI-way would be:

Look in the `System-Settings` under `Applications and Updates` there is a tab called `Updates`.

Also you can invoke the `Update-manager` from your menus.